# JSON request from LOCAL html file to server raises CORS error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at <URL> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: http, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a LOCAL HTML file which contains JSON HTTP Request to a server.
Although the request works in IE, it fails on chrome raising the error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://SERVERNAME/QuestionnaireExample/METHODNAME' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The XMLHTTP code which raises the error is:

```
            $.support.cors = true;

            //upload the questionnaire
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://SERVERNAME/QuestionnaireExample/METHODNAME',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    // CODE for success
                },

                error: function (result) {
                    // CODE for error
                }
            });
        });
```

Diagnostic of the network shows:

### General

```
Request URL: http://SERVERNAME/QuestionnaireExample/METHODNAME
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

### Request headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

As I mentioned, in IE the same code works from local file

```
            $.support.cors = true;

            //upload the questionnaire
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://SERVERNAME/QuestionnaireExample/METHODNAME',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    // CODE for success
                },

                error: function (result) {
                    // CODE for error
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not allowed by browsers to perform a cors request from a local file. It must be run from a webserver. If you open a file like 'C:\temp.html' and run the script there, this error will occur. If you however, open it from 'http://localhost/temp.html', the cors request can be allowed, given that the receiving server allows cors requests and you send a cors request prior to sending the ajax request. I'm not sure if your line $.support.cors = true; is enough to enable cors for that specific request. Could be that this line enables it globally but you still need to attach a cors header to the ajax request.

Comment: Is there no way at all to run CORS from local file? even by reducing Chrome security? In IE it works from fine from local HTML file.

Comment: I'm not a browser expert, but most likely not. Nor would I recommend doing so. Setting up a personal webserver from which you run the file is the recommended way to test it before you put it live on a server on the internet/intranet. It litteraly takes a few minutes at the most to set up such a server.